# Show that $\hat{\mu}(t)$ is of the form $e^{\lambda t^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $X_1, X_2,...$ i.i.d. real random variables. $\displaystyle Y_n=\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $\mu$. Show that $\hat{\mu}(t)$ is of the form $e^{\lambda t^2}$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $Re \lambda\leq 0$.

If we had just $n$ instead of $\sqrt{n}$ it is of the form $e^{\lambda t}$. So if $Y_n/ \sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to $\phi$ then $\hat{\phi}$ is of the form $e^{\lambda t}$. But how could I modify this for $\mu$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's $\hat{\mu}$

Comment: The characteristic function